# How can I identify the command that spawned a process listening on a certain port?

Tags: linux, process, port

I’m using the following version of Linux

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.mydomain.com 5.7.8-35.36.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to find out the command that started a process that listens on a particular port.  Ideally, I’d like to find out from where that command is running.  But I can’t seem to identify the command.  Using nmap I can tell it is a Jetty server …

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ nmap -sV -p 4444 localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-07 20:54 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
4444/tcp open  http    Jetty 5.1.x (Linux/4.4.5-15.26.amzn1.x86_64 amd64 java/1.7.0_79)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.25 seconds
```

Is there any way to figure out what command spawned the Jetty server?

Thanks, - Dave

**Edit:** Here is the output to the suggestion given.

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo lsof -i :4444
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    2140 root   10u  IPv6   9994      0t0  TCP *:krb524 (LISTEN)

[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo ps -p $(pidof java) -o args
ERROR: Process ID list syntax error.
********* simple selection *********  ********* selection by list *********
-A all processes                      -C by command name
-N negate selection                   -G by real group ID (supports names)
-a all w/ tty except session leaders  -U by real user ID (supports names)
-d all except session leaders         -g by session OR by effective group name
-e all processes                      -p by process ID
                                      -q by process ID (unsorted & quick)
T  all processes on this terminal     -s processes in the sessions given
a  all w/ tty, including other users  -t by tty
g  OBSOLETE -- DO NOT USE             -u by effective user ID (supports names)
r  only running processes             U  processes for specified users
x  processes w/o controlling ttys     t  by tty
*********** output format **********  *********** long options ***********
-o,o user-defined  -f full            --Group --User --pid --cols --ppid
-j,j job control   s  signal          --group --user --sid --rows --info
-O,O preloaded -o  v  virtual memory  --cumulative --format --deselect
-l,l long          u  user-oriented   --sort --tty --forest --version
-F   extra full    X  registers       --heading --no-heading --context
                                      --quick-pid
                    ********* misc options *********
-V,V  show version      L  list format codes  f  ASCII art forest
-m,m,-L,-T,H  threads   S  children in sum    -y change -l format
-M,Z  security data     c  true command name  -c scheduling class
-w,w  wide output       n  numeric WCHAN,UID  -H process hierarchy
[davea@mydevbox ~]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**lsof -i:4444**

should list you the processes using 4444. You should start it as root or via sudo to avoid the output restricted to showing only the processes of your id.

Comment: True this lists the processes, but not the full command line of what started the process listening on that port.  In an edit to my question, you can see I ran this command but it just says "java".  I'm tryihng to figure out what command kicked off this Java process.

Comment: ps -f $THATPID will tell you about the parent process id (PPID)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. A simple one involves `ss`:

```
# ss -lntp | grep 22
  LISTEN     0      128                       *:22                    *:*      users:(("sshd",1100,3))
  LISTEN     0      128                      :::22                   :::*      users:(("sshd",1100,4))
```

The options mean: `-l` display ports on which a process is listening, `-n` do not resolve names, `-t` consider only TCP ports, `-p` display the process listening on that port. In this case, you identify the process name (`sshd`, hardly surprising), and the process ID, 1100. For a UDP port, the above command should be morphed to `ss -lnup`.

Or you can use `lsof`:

```
# lsof -i :22
  COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
  sshd    1100 root    3u  IPv4  10089      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISEN)
  sshd    1100 root    4u  IPv6  10091      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN
```

For a UDP port, the command should be `lsof -i UDP:22`.

Lastly, if you want to see the full command line which started a given process, you can do as follows:

```
# ps -p $(pidof sshd) -o args
  COMMAND
  /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

In this case the whole command is not very informative, but occasionally it can be: do you know all the arguments in the invocation of your X server?

```
# ps -p $(pidof X) -o args
  COMMAND
  /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

If you want to learn more, like which chain of processes started the program in question, which *may* point to the user who started the program, use

```
ps auxf
```

which will show you, on the right hand side, the chain of forks leading to a currently running program, with much info as well.

Once you know the process id, `PID`, you can find **all** of the info available to the system in the directory `/proc/PID`, the tricky part being that the info is not immediately self-explanatory. Should you be interested, [this article](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) provides more info, otherwise use `man proc`.

Lastly, do remember that this info is not set in stone: programs can alter at least a part of their own info, see for instance [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/232774/193541).

Comment: Yes, the full commandn line is what I want to see, so it looks like the "ps" command you listed would do the job.  However, when I run it, I get a syntax error using what you have.  The error is included as an edit to my question.

Comment: @Dave It is strange it does not work, it works perfectly on my system: did you try the command directly using the process PID, instead of `$(pidof java)`? Also, you should try the other solution I suggested, *i.e.*, reading the file `/proc/PID/cmdline`.

Comment: I've fallen in love with ss at first sight. Strange that I've not seen it (or don't remember) referred before.

Comment: @GombaiSándor It can do more than `lsof`.